# What happens if you call $(document).ready after the dom has loaded?

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm debugging some code (That I did not write) and some JavaScript is pulled into a page after the Initial DOM.ready call via an ajax request which contains:

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){
    $('#input1').attr('data-defaultvalue',123);
});
```

Am I right in thinking that the code inside that function will never fire as it will be waiting for an event that has already happened.

Comment: You can call it as much as you want. It's harmless, and all the blocks will execute, provided the document is in ready state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is also `$(document).on( "ready", handler )`, deprecated as of
>   jQuery 1.8. This behaves similarly to the ready method but if the
>   ready event has already fired and you try to `.on( "ready" )` the bound
>   handler will not be executed. Ready handlers bound this way are
>   executed after any bound by the other three methods above.

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

You can test it with this code pretty easily. `.ready` will fire, but `.on('ready'...` will not.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        alert(".ready");
    });
    $(document).on('ready', function() { 
        alert(".on('ready')");
    });
}, 5000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n65Leobh/

Comment: You should mention where you are quoting from. You and I quoted exactly the same bit of the jQuery docs.

Answer (score 0):

No that code won't run if it's loaded in after the initial page load. If the `ready` event has already fired and then this code is loaded, it won't be set up to listen for the `ready` event.

Really the only way that won't fire is if the JavaScript is being AJAXed in.

Comment: :p I think thats right though. My code in the example was wrong.

Comment: If you're using .on('ready') then it will only fire when 'ready' fires.

Comment: `$(document).ready()` is just another way to express `$(document).on('ready')`

Comment: No, they behave differently. Refer to documentation: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: You're right. It doesn't really impact the answer though.

Comment: It doesn't now that the O.P. changed the example code.

Answer (score 0):

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> There is also `$(document).on( "ready", handler )`, *deprecated as of
>   jQuery 1.8*. This behaves similarly to the ready method but if the
>   ready event has already fired and you try to `.on( "ready" )` the bound
>   handler will not be executed. Ready handlers bound this way are
>   executed after any bound by the other three methods above.

So it appears you are correct in saying that code will not execute correctly. Changing it to the other ways of binding to the DOM ready event will fix that easily, though.